# Get jQuery autocomplete results using NSPredicate in Objective-C

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, autocomplete, nspredicate

Hi have a piece of jquery code which is as

```
var src = data.split(',');
    jQuery("#stationFrom").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( "\\b" + jQuery.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
            response( jQuery.grep( src, function( item ){
                return matcher.test( item );
            }) );
        },
```

This is basically autocompleting a text field. I'm trying to emulate the same in Objective-C using NSPredicate. The query I tried is

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [possibleTerms filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", inputString]];
return filteredArray;
```

But, this does not return the same results as the jquery autocomplete script above. How can I fix the predicate query to match the jQuery.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"MATCHES" in a predicate does a regular expression match (and "[c]" is for case-insensitivity),
 so this should be similar to your jQuery code:

```
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*\\b%@.*", [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:term]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self MATCHES[c] %@", pattern];
NSArray *filteredArray = [possibleTerms filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

If you want to get all strings in the array that *start* with the given term,
you can use the simpler predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[c] %@", term];
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for the string I am testing with. My array contains the string "DELHI (DLI)" but when i pass the term string "DLI", this predicate doesnt match it whereas the jquery above does.

Comment: @tbag: Can you try again? I have added another `.*` in the pattern.

Comment: @tbag: You are welcome! - (It seems that jQuery implicitly matches "anywhere" in the string, but the predicate MATCHES does not, therefore you have to add `.*` at the start and at the end of the pattern.)